# ¿Por qué mi consulta query no me arroja ningún resultado?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando averiguar del por qué no me arroja ningún resultado mi consulta de mysql.
Adjunto el código que escribí:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Detalles cotizacion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../estilos/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>codigo</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>factor</th>
                <th>contenido</th>
                <th>p. unitario</th>
                <th>cantidad</th>
                <th>subtotal</th>
                <th>#</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        
        require('../cn/cnt.php'); //contiene mi conexión a la BD
        $idCotizacion = $_GET['idCotizacion'];        

        $cot_pendientes = " 
        SELECT DISTINCT id_cotizacion, nombre_cliente, telefono, 
        correo, fecha_cot, auxiliar
        FROM cotizacion INNER JOIN producto_cotizacion 
        ON cotizacion.clave = producto_cotizacion.clave 
        WHERE cotizacion.clave = '$idCotizacion'
        ";       
        
        $consulta = $Oxi->query($cot_pendientes);
        while($rows = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            echo $rows["id_cotizacion"];
        }
        ?>        
      </table>
     </body>

    </html>
```

Entonces, en mi página no arroja NADA, mirad aquí la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con var_dump($consulta), pero igual no me arroja nada, ¿podrían decirme qué estoy haciendo mal?
Ni si quiera un error me manda.

Comment: *Ni si quiera un error me manda.* Hay errores que el programa no captura, debes controlarlo tú, verificando que haya datos en el `$_GET`, que la consulta no es errónea, que hay conexión, que trae datos, etc. No estás controlando nada de eso. Es lo que yo llamo *programación optimista*, o sea, programar creyendo que todo irá bien... esa forma de programar crea códigos débiles, debes aplicar *programación pesimista*, o sea, pensar en todo lo que pueda salir mal, para salirle al frente. Por cierto, pon el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Hice la respectiva edición, mostrando el código en vez de una imagen.

Comment: Se agradece tener el código en texto. Ahora, aplica un poco de pesimismo en tu programa. Pregúntante: *¿qué puede salir mal aquí?* y sal al frente de ello controlando el flujo del programa. Sin manejo de errores un programa no estará nunca bien escrito. No puedes programar pensando en un mundo color de rosa.

Comment: Si quieres avanzar en la depuración puedes revisar el log de errores, o poner estas tres líneas provisionalmente al inicio del script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` así verás en pantalla el motivo del fallo, pero como dije antes, hay una parte del control de errores que debes escribirla tú, para mostrar mensajes personalizados al usuario, evitando la ruptura del código.

Comment: si imprimes la query y la ejecutas directo en la base que te da?

Comment: puedes poner un ``print 'estoy aqui';`` o un ``echo 'estoy aqui';`` para comprobar que no hay fallo de sintaxis, si se muestra estoy aquí es que el fallo es de la consulta y si no muestra nada es porque te habrás comido un ; o alguna pequeña tontería, de todo modos no veo donde esta la conexión de php con tu base de datos. :-)

Comment: intenta cambiando tu consulta por  ``consulta =".$idCotizacion;``

Comment: ya intenté de todo :'(, ni si quiera poniendo al inicio del script el ini_set

Comment: Revisa los logs de PHP. Sale algún error? "no funciona" es un llamado a la adivinación y eso se nos da mal por acá :) Aprovecha todo lo que te ha pasado ACedano

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto mi error, tuve una mala lógica para traer los datos usando mal mi llave foránea:

```
$cot_pendientes = " 
        SELECT DISTINCT id_cotizacion, nombre_cliente, telefono, 
        correo, fecha_cot, auxiliar
        FROM cotizacion INNER JOIN producto_cotizacion 
        ON cotizacion.clave = producto_cotizacion.clave 
        WHERE cotizacion.clave = '$idCotizacion'
```

En mi consulta, `idCotizacion` es un valor entero, mientras que `clave` es una cadena, por lo tanto, era un resultado vacío y no me mostraba ningún error.

Mi solución es el siguiente, la sentencia queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
require('../cn/cnt.php');
$clave = $_GET['claveCotizacion'];

$cliente = " SELECT nombre_cliente, telefono, correo, direccion, fecha_cot, clave 
FROM cotizacion WHERE clave = '$clave' ORDER BY clave ASC LIMIT 1 ";

$sql = $Oxi->query($cliente);
while ($rows = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <h3><?php echo $rows["nombre_cliente"]; ?></h3>
    <h3><?php echo $rows["telefono"]; ?></h3>
    <h3><?php echo $rows["correo"]; ?></h3>
    <h3><?php echo $rows["direccion"]; ?></h3>
<?php
}
?>
```

Gracias por su ayuda a los demás desarrolladores que me dieron sus sabias sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo donde se aplica la *programación pesimista*. Como dije en comentarios, tu tarea como programador es pensar en todo aquello que pueda salir mal y controlarlo desde el código. Un código que no prevea todos los posibles errores no será nunca un código robusto, porque cuando algunos de los controles falle, el código se quedará mudo o no sabrá para dónde tirar.

Es un código más largo, claro, pero no siempre las cosas son fáciles y el mundo no siempre es color de rosa, qué más quisiera uno... los problemas surgen, y hay que saber enfrentarlos.

Cabe decir que, en un programa avanzado, esta forma de programar te ayudará con más claridad a incorporar una política de manejo de errores, donde mostrarías por ejemplos banners en la parte superior con mensajes de error para el usuario o cosas así. En producción no conviene mostrar mensajes de error del SGBD como he hecho aquí: `printf("Error en la consulta: %s",$Oxi->error)`, lo he puesto así, para si falla, conocer el motivo del fallo y corregirlo con más rapidez.

He aquí el código, espero no haber errado en nada. He acortado los nombres de algunas variables que pueden permanecer genéricos sin por ello dificultar la comprensión del código. No hay que escribir un código verboso sin necesidad.

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['idCotizacion'] ?? null;   
    if ($id) {
        require('../cn/cnt.php');
        $sql=" 
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT id_cotizacion, 
                nombre_cliente, 
                telefono, 
                correo, 
                fecha_cot, 
                auxiliar
            FROM cotizacion 
            INNER JOIN producto_cotizacion 
                ON cotizacion.clave = producto_cotizacion.clave 
            WHERE cotizacion.clave = '$id'";       
    
        if($rs = $Oxi->query($sql)) {
            if($rs->num_rows > 0) {
                while($rows = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    printf("%s\n", $rows["id_cotizacion"]);
                }
            } else {
                echo "No hay filas encontradas";
            }
        } else {
            #Evita mostrar mensajes del SGBD en producción
            printf("Error en la consulta: %s",$Oxi->error);
        }
    } else {
        echo "No hay conexión";
    }
} else {
    echo "No hay datos en GET";
}
   
?>
```